# Regex to split csv, values surrounded by quotes, values have quotes

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, datatable

I'm not very good at Regex and I'm tasking with loading a csv into a datatable with powershell.  The csv has its values surrounded by quotes, separated by a comma.  Trouble is, some of the rows consists of column values that include a quote in the value itself.

```
$csvSplit = "($csvdelimiter)"
$csvSplit += '(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)'
$regexOptions = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::ExplicitCapture
```

The lines that throw this off have values in them where the value might say something like `3-1/8"` as part of the value.  I'm a beginner with PowerShell as well, but I'm really not sure what to do to change the regex so that it omits these types of situations.

### Update

Trying these solutions didn't seem to solve the problem wholeheartedly, just moved the problem to a different spot.  I'm led to believe that the issue is with the CSV itself, but I haven't been able to find an example of bad formatting.

Comment: Are the _embedded_ `"` instances not _escaped_? Does your input really have values such as `"3-1/8""`?

Comment: yes, indeed that is the case.  I'm not sure what the method was on how this CSV was generated.

Comment: I'm not that good at regex, but this seems to work: `"(.*?)"(,|$)`. The idea here is, match anything before "double-quote immediately followed by comma or end of line". https://regex101.com/r/4BZkgt/3

Comment: Looking at the link you sent and I'm confused.  It seems to match the cell values.  I'm trying to match on the real delimiters so I can split each line by them

Comment: Don't use Regex. Use something designed to properly parse a CSV.

Comment: @JakeSmith Brackets denote capturing groups, so just remove the first set and keep the second - `".*?"(,|$)`. Link updated.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `"` chars. *embedded* in your fields are *not escaped*:

- you cannot reliably use `Import-Csv` (or `ConvertFrom-Csv`).

  - for field-internal `"` chars. to be properly parsed, they'd have to be represented as `""` (doubled).
- a *manual parsing* effort is required, which will only work if you make *assumptions*.

If the assumption can be made that *embedded* (field-interior) `"` are *never directly followed by `,`*, you can try the following approach (PSv4+):

```
# Sample array of CSV lines.
# Note that some fields have unescaped internal " chars. 
$csv = @'
"col1","col2"
"one","3-1/0""
"normal","line"
"3-1/1"","two"
"3" of rain","today"
'@ -split '\r?\n'    


$lineNo = 0
# Process the CSV lines one by one.
# Note: Replace `$csv |` with `Get-Content yourFile.csv`
$csv | ForEach-Object {
  # Extract the field values based on the assumption above.
  $fieldValues = ([regex]::Matches($_, '"(.*?)"(?:,|$)')).ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value })
  if (++$lineNo -eq 1) { # 1st == header line
    # Create an object *template* with the 1st line's field values as 
    # property names.
    $propNames = $fieldValues
    $ohtAux = [ordered] @{}
    foreach ($propName in $propNames) { $ohtAux[$propName] = $null }
    $objTemplate = [pscustomobject] $ohtAux
  } else { # 2nd and subsequent lines: data lines
    # Clone the template object.
    $obj = $objTemplate.psobject.Copy()
    # Fill the clone's properties with the field values.
    $i = 0
    foreach ($propName in $propNames) { $obj.$propName = $fieldValues[$i++] }
    # Output the clone.
    $obj
  }
}
```

The above yields:

```
col1       col2
----       ----
one        3-1/0"
normal     line
3-1/1"     two
3" of rain today
```

*Caveat*: This solution will be relatively *slow*, given that a script block must be executed for each input line.

Notes:

- Regex `'"(.*?)"(?:,|$)'` non-greedily `*?` matches a `"`-enclosed value as long as the closing `"` is either immediately followed by a `,` or (`|`) the end of the line (`$`).

  - Enclosing `.*?` in `(...)` - a capture group - makes the string between the `"` instances (i.e., the raw field value) available as the 2nd element (index `1`) of the `.Groups` property of the match object returned by `[regex]::Matches()`
  - Note that the `?:` in `(?:,|$)` denotes a *non-capturing* group, which was chosen because what the group matches need not be accessed later. Aside from signaling which groups are of interest later, this makes the regex slightly more efficient.
  - Note: [wp78de's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51237153/45375) shows a simpler and faster approach based on using the regex to match the *separators* rather than field values, which *directly* returns the raw field values.
- `.ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value })` therefore outputs all raw field values and saves them as an array in variable `$fieldValues`.
- `$ohtAux = [ordered] @{}` and `foreach ($propName in $propNames) { $ohtAux[$propName] = $null }` defines an auxiliary hashtable with ordered keys and creates (initially empty) entries for the 1st input line's field values, which are assumed to be the column names; `[pscustomobject] $ohtAux` then converts the hashtable to a custom object, which serves as the template for the objects to output for the data lines to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a comma as the delimiter, this should do the trick:

```
((Get-Content '.\split.txt' -raw) -split  '"?,"?|^"|"$' -ne '')
```

- I split at a `,` with optional `"` before and after
- and removes surrounding quotes at the beginning and the end.
- To get rid of extra empty matches (see [demo](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oxf)) I use the `-ne` operator.

Caveat: You may lose a quote if it is not part of a balanced pair of double quotes.

Comment: Nicely done; that is indeed the simplest way to get an array of the raw field values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a reg-ex?  Is there some reason the built-in Powershell CSV converter won't work for you?

```
$csv = Get-Content .\split.txt | ConvertFrom-CSV
```

or something similar.  I would suggest you start with a smaller file than 32Gb to test your approach.  As others mention there are lots of pitfalls with quoted data but as long as your input is formatted correctly and you are willing to wait for PowerShell to read 32Gb this may work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've been looking it up and trying to understand it.  What exactly do I do with $csv now?

Comment: Something like `foreach($row in $csv) { $n = $row.N; $o = $row.O }` to loop through your data?  If your first row is used as the column names then in this example the first row would be something like `M,N,O,P` or similar.

Comment: I see.  I'll play around with it and see if it works.  Currently I'm seeing how long `ConvertFrom-CSV` takes to run on this file.  With 617 columns (I know, ridiculous), it seems to be pretty mad at me for asking it to do this on a Sunday evening.

Comment: Check using `Get-Content -Head 10000` and vary the number. I have tried using `ConvertFrom-CSV` on data in the format you've mentioned and it doesn't like unmatched quotes. `"3-1/8"","next",` is read in as one value: `3-1/8",this"`

Comment: The reason that `ConvertFrom-Csv` (or `Import-Csv`, which is the  better alternative tot he  `Get-Content ... | ConvertFrom-Csv` combo) doesn't work here is that the field-internal `"` chars. aren't _escaped_ (they'd have to be _doubled_).

Comment: Incorrectly formatted data is the bane of programmers everywhere.  Unless you are able to clean up the source you will be fighting your parsing forever.  Don't let the namespace fool you but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7
is the built-in way to read properly delimited text files.